# Are the basis of kernel space and the basis of image space independent for full rank linear transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, finite-fields

Considering $T$ as a linear transformation from $\mathbb{F}^n$ to $\mathbb{F}^m$ of full rank $m\leq n$, we know that $\dim(\operatorname{ker}(T))=n-\dim(\operatorname{im}(T))=n-m$ by the rank–nullity theorem. This means that we can take an $m\times n$ matrix $T_{\text{im}}$ to represent $\operatorname{im}(T)$ and an $n\times (n-m)$ matrix $T_{\text{ker}}$ to represent $\operatorname{ker}(T)$. The question is that, does the row space of $T_{\text{im}}$ always have no intersection with the column space of $T_{\text{ker}}$?

I'm wondering if there is a concrete counterexample for this, particularly when $\mathbb{F}$ is a finite field. Because if the above vector spaces are all finite-dimensional and equipped with an inner product, we can always take $T_{\text{im}}$ and $T_{\text{ker}}$ consisting of orthonormal row vectors and orthonormal column vectors, respectively. In this case, one can easily verify that the row space of $T_{\text{im}}$ is the orthogonal complement of the column space of $T_{\text{ker}}$ in $\mathbb{F}^n$, so the intersection between them would always be empty.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140266/discussion-on-question-by-thinkpad-are-the-basis-of-kernel-space-and-the-basis-o).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $\mathbb{F}=\operatorname{GF}(2)$, let $T_{\text{im}}=\begin{pmatrix}1&1&0\\1&1&1\end{pmatrix}$. We verify that
$$
\begin{pmatrix}1&1&0\\1&1&1\end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\end{pmatrix},
$$
which allows us to let $T_{\text{ker}}=\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}$. Clearly, the row space of $T_{\text{im}}$ has an intersection with the column space of $T_{\text{ker}}$ in this case.

Answer (score 4):

Take the map $$T: \mathbb F^2 \to \mathbb F^2, (x,y) \mapsto (0,x).$$
Then you have equality $\operatorname{ker}(T) = \operatorname{im}(T)$, and so $\dim (\operatorname{ker}(T) + \operatorname{im}(T)) = \dim \operatorname{ker}(T) = 1$.

This works for any field $\mathbb F$.

> Obviously, if the vector space is finite-dimensional and equipped with an inner product, we can easily argue that $\dim(im(T)+ker(T))=n$ by way of contradiction, so hopefully we can construct a counterexample on finite fields.

Not sure what this has to do with the inner product, but in general this is false, as shown by my example.

Comment: In $\mathbb R^2$, it's a projection composed with a reflexion :).

Comment: @StéphaneJaouen Only if we choose the standard inner product, though...

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I apologize for missing something before, that is, $T$ should be non-degenerate. Could you please have a look at this updated version? Anyway, I have given my upvote because your answer is correct for the previous question.